# Retrieving from firebase to array

Tags: google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polyline

I am a newbie in firebase. In my web app I have stored a set or coordinates in firebase. The structure looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ca0gMa6xZ4ZIHWG_Ogv5DjWmZHJjMKYt):

```
{
  "pointdata" : {
    "-L0eZoI7sULutu5nVOgw" : {
      "lat" : 42.76314586689492,
      "lng" : -91.966552734375
    },
    "-L0eZoozb2cf7mC3DUTy" : {
      "lat" : 41.72213058512578,
      "lng" : -90.604248046875
    },
    "-L0eZp084Cs54IJ5IBoA" : {
      "lat" : 41.41801503608025,
      "lng" : -89.351806640625
    },
    "-L0eZpBHcXve-jEy_TYk" : {
      "lat" : 41.94314874732696,
      "lng" : -88.0224609375
    },
    "-L0eZpaftCzzM4EmXz4D" : {
      "lat" : 42.72280375732727,
      "lng" : -88.231201171875
    }
  }
}
```

I need these coordinates to be retrieved and stored as an array or arraylist:

```
{ [lat1, lng1] [lat2,lng2] .... }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Did it, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Get the points from database then push an array in `forEach` loop :

```
var pointsArr = [];
firebase.database().ref('pointdata').once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(point=>{
       pointsArr.push([point.val().lat, point.val().lng]);
  })
   console.log(pointsArr); // shows your points in array
})
```

Comment: Thank you , and a followup question. I am trying to use the afformentioned pointsArr to create a polyline path (setcoords) and with that , a polyline. My app seems to get stuck in the following loop :                                                                   
      for (int c = 0; c < pointsArr.length; c++){
     var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArr[c][1], pointsArr[c][2])
     setofcoords.push(coords);
 }

Comment: I think `new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArr[c][1], pointsArr[c][2])` should be `new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArr[c][0], pointsArr[c][1])`